# Regression with multiple functional forms - Which correction should I use?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, p-value, bonferroni

I have spent a lot of time on this without finding a good solution.

I am running a regression with a variable of interest to me (X) and various covariates. Unfortunately, X appeared at first as non-significant. Therefore, I  tried different functional forms in my regression (e.g. X², ln(X), exp(X)...) and finally found X to be significant with the functional form ln(x).

1) Even if many researchers do this, I have the feeling that I should either adjust the p-value associated with X or my significance level to account for the fact that I tried various functional forms. Am I correct?

2) If yes, which correction should I use? I have the feeling that the classical corrections such as Sidak and Bonferroni, apply when you have multiple outcomes (Y). In addition, it seems to me that they are way too stringent in my case, as the transformations I apply to my X are positively correlated amongst one another and with X. Would there be a correction rather simple such as a modified version of Bonferroni or Sidak taking correlation into account that applies in my case? (as it is for a research paper, do not hesitate to give me references).

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It's good that you are concerned about interpreting your p-values here, but I'd strongly advise you not to use this approach (even with a correction). If you must try out a bunch of different transformations/functional forms, perhaps you could do it on a subset of the data and then test your result on a hold out dataset. Or to put it another way, I refer you to the name of this website for a reasonable solution.

Comment: You could use (restricted) splines instead of transformations. Although you still have to chose the amount of 'knots', they are more flexible compared to a single transformation. Moreover, some suggest 4 or 5 knots usually do the trick. On the other hand, If you really want transformations, take a look at the 'mfp' package in R. More specifically the algorithm it uses to pick transformations. This package does not have a complete multiple testing 'correction', but does account for increasing model complexity.

Comment: I like the solution of mkt which has the merit of simplicity. I have the feeling that I should try to find a way to split my sample in two randomly a number of time (say 500) and see how many times my variable of interest comes out as significant. Do you think such a solution makes sense? Concerning the answer of IWS, I have never heard of a paper using restricted splines in my domain - I will document myself on it. Thank you both very much for your answers, that helps me a great deal!

Comment: It's hard to suggest the best strategy without knowing your analytical goal. But there are many strategies (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) and an extensive literature on cross-validation that you could consult. Also, I would encourage you to think about what you are getting out of statistical significance here; it may not be very helpful in your specific case. Finally, I agree with IWS that splines/GAMs may be a useful approach.

Comment: To close the topic: I finally decided based on your advices to perform two cross-validation techniques, that is LOOCV (Leave One Out Cross Validation) and K-Fold cross validation (with k=2 to have samples of reasonable size). The cross validation techniques as well as the AIC and BIC points out that the model with functionnal form is better, which lead me to keep it this way. Thank you all for your answers!